# Como utilizar un motor de reglas en C# en tiempo de ejecucion

Tags: c#, .net

Digamos que el modelo es un dispositivo (que podria ser un aire acondicionado), un actuador (que se encarga de, por ejemplo, bajar la temperatura) y un sensor (que solo toma la temperatura del ambiente).

La idea seria que el usuario defina sus propias reglas. Por ejemplo, si la temperatura ambiente es mayor a 28°, que encienda el aire y lo ponga a 24°.

Segun vi, existe NRules. Pero no encuentro un ejemplo claro de como definir reglas en tiempo de ejecucion por el usuario.

Comment: Creo que esto te daría una idea para comenzar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6560284/8933039

Comment: Sin un ambito exacto de lo que quieres hacer y alguna prueba que nos ayude a entender tu problema, esta pregunta es demasiado amplia. Existe una amplia variedad de cosas que puedes hacer para permitir que tu usuario cree sus reglas, pero sin un contexto... es imposible. Te recomiendo pasar por [ask] y [mcve], solo para que nos dejes entenderte mejor :)

Comment: Las primeras 3 lines explican el contexto, solo eso necesitas saber....
Un ejemplo, es justamente lo que quiero que me respondan.

Comment: En realidad no explicas mucho con eso solo cuentas una historia aqui se ayudan con problemas plateados con codigo es a lo que se refiere @NaCl, y te dice que muestres una prueba o un error que tengas para poder ayudarte, ya que no es un sitio de opiniones, si no de preguntas concretas

Comment: @R.Nuñez: Un problema bien planteado no necesariamente lleva código _(Y se ha visto el caso en este sitio)_. OP: un ejemplo de lo que pides es demasiado sin entender el camino por donde quieres ir, por eso, ven con un problema concreto luego de que hayas probado NRule o tu propia invención y deja que hagamos el resto :)